# Java : can't call overloaded constructor

Tags: java, constructor

here I am trying to call overloaded constructor after some condition has met in my main() program , which is given by variable a. Code works fine when I am using only default constructor , but I need to call overloaded constructor at some point and it fails . folowing is code:

overloaded constructor :

```
public Paddle(int a){

   if(a ==1){
       ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(paddle1));
       image = ii.getImage();
   }
   else {
       ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(paddle2));
       image = ii.getImage();
   }
    width = image.getWidth(null);
    height = image.getHeight(null);
  resetState();
  }

//      further initialization --
```

default constructor :

```
 public Paddle(){

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(paddle));
        image = ii.getImage();

        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
        System.out.println(height+" "+width);
        resetState();
 }
```

thanks for help in advance, further queries can be asked but I think this piece of code has some problem . Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to read your first "block" of code.  Could you format it to look like your second block of code? (EDIT: Thanks for the new formatting!)

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  If there's a stacktrace, post it.

Comment: formatting done 
Program compiles successfully but there is some run time error the moment constructor is called 
(edit: I will try to get stack trace , never used that before)

paddle1 and paddle are valid links to the resource <image file>

Comment: its not enough code. perhaps paddle1 is wrong, perhaps you should declare ImageIcon ii before the if case. At which line the program breaks?

Comment: paddle1 is correct actually in order to load image based on the value of a , I am using Imageicon ii  under if case

Comment: ok, now we have the whole constructor xD answer below should be correct. you don't set image

Comment: What is failing?  You should post a stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer

You are not setting the instance variable `image` in the overloaded constructor.

#### Correct Way

The way you are doing it is violating [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ( Don't Repeat Yourself )!

The best way is to make the `no arg` constructor call the overloaded one and then set the instance variable `image` in one place.

```
public Paddle(final int i) 
{ 
   if (i==1) { this.image = one thing } 
   else 
   { this.image = another thing } 
}

public Paddle() { this(0); }
```

A better way would be to just pass in the resource to a single constructor and be done with it, without seeing all the code, this looks overly complicated.

Comment: Do we know that?  He hasn't shown us the rest of his 1-arg constructor.

Comment: this doesn''t help either . I will try to explain the situation:
there is Main class where value of a is set , depending on the conditions , and thus constructor is loaded . For intital default case when constructor had no arguments it works fine , but moment constructor with argument is called it, game stops.

Comment: You must see the stacktrace of the exception being printed to standard output. If in Eclipse, look the Console view. If in other IDE, look in the equivalent of that. If on the command line, use java instead of javaw to see the output in a text window, or use the Java console.

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE , I am trying to get stack trace , I am new to this